# Difference in creating settings manually vs using settings.settings in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, app-config, settings.settings

Is there a difference in manually creating your (let's say db connection string) in the config file vs using the settings interface? I have heard that it's safe to use settings interface. Any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence it is basically the same thing.  Settings.settings is just an additional config file spec with a UI interface to be able to edit your values.  Unless you use [Windows Authentication for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [encrypt your configuration entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx) , you expose a security risk.  With SQL Server, personally I would choose Windows Auth.